# stopImmediatePropagation() of sibling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I show a search field on some text click, and hide it on search input blur.

But if I click on the search button I don’t want to hide the input field, and prevent it from being hidden (because of the blur). I tried to `stopImmediatePropagation()` without any luck.

Here’s some code:

```
// Not working. when search button is pressed, disable hiding the search input
$('.search-contacts-container > button').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  alert('xxx');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})

// when search input is blurred, hide it
$('#search-contacts').on('blur', function() {
  $('.search-contacts-container').addClass('visuallyhidden');
  $('#search-contacts').attr('required', 'false').blur();
})

// when search input is focused, show it
$('#search-contacts').on('focus', function() {
  $('.search-contacts-container').removeClass('visuallyhidden');
  $('#search-contacts').attr('required', 'true');
})

// on search text click, show the search input
$('.js-show-search').on('click touchstart', function() {
  if ($('.search-contacts-container').is('.visuallyhidden')) {
    $('.search-contacts-container').removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    $('#search-contacts').attr('required', 'true').focus();
  } else {
    $('.search-contacts-container').addClass('visuallyhidden');
    $('#search-contacts').attr('required', 'false').blur();
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<span class="js-show-search" title="Search for contacts">Search</span>

<form action="search" method="post" class="form-search  search-contacts-container  visuallyhidden">
   <input type="text" id="search-contacts" placeholder="Search" required="false" />
   <button type="submit" class="form-search__button" title="Search"></button>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/un775/

Any ideas?

Comment: `sstopImmedediatePropagation` doesn't prevent the `blur` event, it prevents the `click` and `touchstart` events on the button from bubbling up.

Comment: `>` is a immediate descendant selector. In your case button in not

Comment: @Satpal button is a descendant of .search-contacts-container (`<form>`)

Comment: @Alex, descendant but not immediate following .search-contacts-container

Answer (score 1):

Check out my new JsFiddle. I use this method on day to day tasks. I hope it helps you.

Basically what you are doing is adding a background that masks everything behind it, and then adding a click even listener to it that hides everything. The form/input is in front of the background allowing you to interact with it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="js-show-search">...</div>

<form id="search-contacts" class="hide">...</form>
<div id="background" class="hide"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var searchContact, background;

searchContact = $('#search-contacts');
background = $('#background');

$('#js-show-search').on('click', function(){
    //remove .hide to show elements
});

$('#background.close').on('click', function(){
    //add .hide to hide elements
});
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#search-contacts {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
    display: none!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/un775/7/

Comment: Update-Sorry it doesn’t work. When I blur the `<input>`, it’s not being hidden

Comment: Looks like I over looked something important. I edited my answer with a new jsfiddle.